# Free IP to country database that can be used in commercial products

Tags: php, ip, country

There are already topics for IP to Country databases, but my question is specifically for database that can be used in commercial products.

My product is extension for Magento e-commerce open source platform. User can buy the extension and install it on his website. I want to add to extension new functionality which will make possible to show different things for each country. And for this I want to use IP to Country database.

I cannot show attribution on frontend to end user. This means the visitor of website where extension is installed won't see the link, but if buyer of my extension opens the file to view the code he/she will see it. I can also include the link inside extension description, but again this will be seen only by extension buyer and not to visitor of website where the extension will be installed.

Does anybody know for any free IP to country database that can be used in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: [GeoLite2 Free Downloadable Databases](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/)

This should work for you if you are only looking for something free...